# I need help understanding the modulo operator

Tags: c#, modulo

I was trying to recreate my C++ factor program from a few years ago in my new language C#. All I could remember is that it possibly involved a modulo, and possibly didn't.  I knew that it involved at least one for and if statement. However, when I started trying to recreate it I kept getting nothing near what should be. I thought it had something to do with me not understanding loops, but it turns out I understand loops just fine. What I don't understand is how to use the modulo when performing math operations.

for instance what am I doing when I say something like:

(ignore that it might not actually work, it's just an example)

```
if(12 % 2  == 0)
 {
  Console.WriteLine("I don't understand.");
 }
```

This kind of thing I don't quite have a grasp of yet. I realize that it is taking the remainder, and that's all I can grasp, not how it's actually used in real programming. I managed to get my factor program to work in C# after a bit of thinking and tinkering, it again doesn't mean I understand this operator or its uses.  I no longer have access to the old C++  file.

Comment: As for how it's used in 'real programming', here's another example - suppose you have a time in seconds, and you need to convert it to minutes and seconds . . . .

Answer (score 4):

The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division. In your example the remainder is equal to 0 and the *if* evaluates to *true* (0 == 0). A classic example is when it's used to see if a number is even or not.

```
if (number % 2 == 0) {
   // even
} else {
   // odd
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Think of modulo like a circle with a pointer (spinner), easiest example is a clock.

[image: https://latex.artofproblemsolving.com/f/4/d/f4daa2601de14fddf3d8441e16cc322a25e85354.png]

Notice how at the top it is zero.

The modulo function maps any value to one of those values on the spinner, think of the value to the left of the `%` as the number of steps around the spinner, and the second value as the number of total steps in the spinner, so we have the following.

0 % 12 = 0

1 % 12 = 1

12 % 12 = 0

13 % 12 = 1

We always start at 0.

So if we go 0 steps around a 12 step spinner we are still at 0, if we go 1 step from zero we are on 1, if we go 12 steps we are back at 0. If we go 13 we go all the way around and end at 1 again.

I hope this helps you visualize it.

It helps when you are using structures like an array, and you want to cycle through them.  Imagine you have an array of the days of the week, 7 elements (mon-sunday). You want to always display the day 3 days from the current day. well Today is tuesday, so the array element is `days[1]`, if we want to get the day 3 days from now we do `days[1+3];` now this is alright, but what if we are at saturday `(days[5])` and want to get 3 days from there? well we have `days[5+3]` which is an index out of bounds error as our array has only 7 elements (max index of 6) and we tried to access the 8th element.

However, knowing what you know about modulos and spinners now you can do the following:

`string threeDaysFromNow = days[(currentDay + 3)%7];` When it goes over the bounds of the array, it wraps around and starts at the beginning again. There are many applications for this. Just remember the visualization of spinners, that is when it clicked in my head.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator `%` returns the remainder of a division operation. For example, where `13 / 5 = 2`, `13 % 5 = 3` (using integer math).

It's a common tactic to check a value against `% 2` to see if it is even. If it is even, the remainder will be 0, otherwise it will be 1.

As for your specific use of it, you are doing `12 % 2` which is not only 0, but will *always* be 0. That will always make the if condition `12 % 2 == 0` true, which makes the if rather redundant.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned, it's commonly used for checking even/odd but also can use it to iterate loops at intervals, or split files into mod chunks.  i personally use mod for clock face type problems as my data often navigates a circle.

the register is in mod for example an 8 bit register rolls over at 2^8 so so can force compliance into a register size var = mod(var, 256)

and the last thing i know about mod is that it is used in checksum and random number generation, but i haven't gone into the why for those. at all

Answer (score -2):

An example where you could use this is in indexing arrays in certain `for` loops. For example, take the simple equation that defines the new pixel value of a resampled image using bicubic interpolation:

[image] where [image]

Don't worry what bicubic interpolation exactly is for the moment, we're just concerned about executing what seems to be two simple `for` loops: one for index `i` and one for index `j`. Note that the vector 'a' is 16 numbers long.

A simple `for` loop someone would try could be:

```
int n= 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{

  for(int j = 0; i < 4; ++j)
  {
    pxy += a[n] * pow(x,i) * pow(y,j);  // p(x,y)
    n++;  // n = 15 when finished
  }

}
```

Or you could do it in one `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
   int i_new = floor(i / 4.0);  // i_new provides indices 0-3 incrementing every 4 iterations of loop       
   int j_new = i % 4;           // j_new is reset to 0 when i is a multiple of 4       
   pxy += a[i] * pow(x,i_new) * pow(y,j_new);  // p(x,y)
}
```

Printing `i_new` and `j_new` in the loop:

```
i_new   j_new
0       0
0       1
0       2
0       3

1       0
1       1
1       2
1       3

2       0
2       1
2       2
2       3

3       0
3       1
3       2
3       3
```

As you can see, `%` can be very useful.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Comment: After re-reading the question, you're right. I was caught in giving an example.